# Is there a design pattern for passing a derived object to a base class method without casting?

Tags: design-patterns

Is there a design pattern that can refactor the following code into something that is type safe at compile-time (i.e. no type casting)?

```
public abstract class Base1 {
    public abstract void DoStuff(Base2 b);
}

public class Specific1 : Base1 {
    public override void DoStuff(Base2 b) {
        var s = (Specific2)b;
        // do clever things with s
    }
}

public abstract class Base2 { }
public class Specific2 : Base2 { }
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you might want to consider [double dispatch](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DoubleDispatchExample) here, i.e. have a call to `b.DoStuff(`) in `Specific1#DoStuff()`. `Base1` shouldn't become too clever about what to do with other classes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access specific methods that are introduced in Specific2 (and thus not defined in its base class, Base2), you have no other option than to cast it.

Unless, you use generics (in C# f.e.):

```
public abstract class Base1<T> where T : Base2
{
    public abstract void DoStuff( T b );
}

public class Specific1 : Base1<Specific2>
{
    public override void DoStuff( Specific2 b ) {}
}
```

But, this puts a limitation on your `Specific1` class of course, that is you can only pass `Specific2` instances to the `DoStuff` method.

Answer (score 1):

In Java you can do:

```
public abstract class Base1<T extends Base1> {
public abstract void DoStuff(T b);
}

public class Specific1 extends Base1<Specific2> {
    public override void DoStuff(T b) {
        var T = b;
        // do clever things with s
    }
}
```